# laravel custom validation rule for property if relation's property is not the same

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make validation rule which will let me check if the name is unique if relation's prop is same.
So model Profile has 'name' property and 'contract' relation. I want name to be unique if contract.org_id is same. So if two models have same contract.org_id their names should be different. If contract.org_id are different then these two models can have same name

profiles table

- contract_id
- name
- ... other props

contracts table

- org_id
- ... other props

Profile's name can't be same with another profile's name if their contracts have same org_id prop

Answer (score 0):

I'd first look into the Rule::unique method

```
Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique

You might do something like

```
Rule::unique('your_model_table', 'name')->where(function ($query) {
    $query->join('contract', 'column1', 'column2'); // Add the necessary join clause to only worry about models with the same contract id
})
```

Comment: why do we need column2? I think in your scheme it should be $query->join('contract', 'org_id'). But still it doesn't work

Comment: @PttRulez that wouldn't be a valid join then. You might have to change the `on` to a `where` and enter the org id if it's coming from the POST/PUT request. I would need more information about your controller and form request to guide you any more

Comment: Thank you for ur help. I have edited my post. I have proposed to do more simple rule (without going inside relation table) if i don't manage to constrcut the original rule.